# Single insert to mysql table locks whole database

Tags: mysql, locking, myisam

I have MyIsam table with few records (about 20):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `_cm_dtstd_37` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NUMBER` int(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'str',
  `DESCRIPTION` char(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'str',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `PHONE` (`NUMBER`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='==CORless Numbers=='
```

Single insert:

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO _cm_dtstd_37 VALUES(NULL, 55555, '55555')
```

takes very long time to execute (about 5 to 7 **minutes**) and makes MySql server put every next query on 'wait' state. No other query (even those that read/write other tables) is executed until first INSERT is done.

I have no idea how to debug this and where to search for any clue.

All inserts to another tables work well, whole database works great when not inserting to feral table.

Answer (score 1):

That is one big reason for moving from MyISAM to InnoDB.

MyISAM allows multiple simultaneous reads (`SELECT`), but any type of write locks the entire table, even against writes.

InnoDB uses "row locking", so *most* simultaneous accesses to a table have no noticeable impact on each other.